# Assist with Excel Search

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to search an excel sheet with 18 different items ... but I want to be able to search any of those items and return all the data for that row... this is an inventory list that has multiple identifying factors... username, serial number, item type, user id, etc...

if I search for the serial number ... I want to be able to return all the data that is connected with it... the username that it is assigned to, that individuals ID, and anything else that is assgined to that individual .... I have tried using VLOOKUP... but it only returns the data based off the left most cell...

Not sure if I am explaining this correctly .... I want to be able to search the entire sheet for a specific item and return with ...who has it, and what else that person also has ... ??? I guess is the problem....

UPDATE***

if I create a search box on a different sheet to look at the data on this sheet...I want to be able to put in the SN of any device and get the complete row of info for all pieces ... if I put 1237 in the box I should get john, rogers, 1237, d123, d456

and the same if I put d456 in the box

[Dummy Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhA4b.png)

Comment: VLOOKUP searches from left to right. XLOOKUP can lookup any column, either left or right from the reference column. This is available in Office 365. Otherwise you should combine INDEX and MATCH.

Comment: to further explain .... say I look up an laptop serial number (xyz)... it should return who has that item and any other item they have .... but if I look up a different item (abc) that same person has ... it should show every item he/she has....... every item is unique and not duplicated in the sheet

Comment: `=INDEX(result_column,MATCH(lookup_value,lookup_column,0))`

Comment: tried ... based off chart I added ... for first name...I put b123 in the search

=INDEX(C4:G9,MATCH(J4,C4:C9,0))  <--- this in J5 for first name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function would work, provided that the search item is listed once in your data:

```
=INDEX($C$5:$G$9,
       SUMPRODUCT(($C$5:$G$9=$J$4)*(ROW($C$5:$G$9)))-ROW($C$4:$G$4),
       MATCH($I5,$C$4:$G$4,0))
```

The data range is indexed and the SUMPRODUCT is used to return the row number of where the value is found within your data. The row number of the header is subtracted to represent the row number in your indexed data. The match-part returns the *n*th instance of the header that matches the type you're searching for.
This results in the value you look for.

Comment: Thank you all for the help and support !!!